# PDF to EPUB in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, pdf, epub

In my project I am making a book reader. It takes books in PDF format and I have to show them in EPUB format. I don't know how to convert PDF to EPUB. This is implemented in CALIBRE software. EPUB (Electronic Publication) is an open e-book standard basically designed for reflowable content. Refer: [EPUB Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPUB)

Please help by providing some guidance as to how I should I proceed?

Comment: Please re-check the question. I have edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout this tutorial:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/44395/Conversion-of-PDF-to-EPUB-Format

Kind regards,
Bo

Comment: is there any other method also?

Comment: You might want to checkout Calibre source code for ideas but it is written in Python/C++. Here is how to download code/setup dev env for it:  http://manual.calibre-ebook.com/develop.html

Comment: any other software of such kind? So that i can get more idea about how to make it.

Comment: Maybe: http://www.fbreader.org/